# Getting '[libprotobuf ERROR external/com_google_protobuf/src/google/protobuf/descriptor_database.cc:642] File already exists in database:' in Ubuntu

Tags: c++, tensorflow, build, protocol-buffers, bazel

After finishing building a project with Bazel, I'm getting the following error while executing the binary on Ubuntu 20.04.

```
[libprotobuf ERROR external/com_google_protobuf/src/google/protobuf/descriptor_database.cc:642] File already exists in database: tensorflow/compiler/mlir/quantization/tensorflow/quantization_options.proto
[libprotobuf FATAL external/com_google_protobuf/src/google/protobuf/descriptor.cc:1986] CHECK failed: GeneratedDatabase()->Add(encoded_file_descriptor, size): 
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'google::protobuf::FatalException'
  what():  CHECK failed: GeneratedDatabase()->Add(encoded_file_descriptor, size): 
Aborted (core dumped)
```

It seems there is a duplication related to protobuf library, but I'm struggling to figure out where the duplication came from, because the reproducer only depends on tensorflow without any plugins.

Codes for the reproducer are below.

WORKSPACE

```
workspace(name = "reproducer")

load("@bazel_tools//tools/build_defs/repo:http.bzl", "http_archive")

http_archive(
    name = "bazel_skylib",
    sha256 = "74d544d96f4a5bb630d465ca8bbcfe231e3594e5aae57e1edbf17a6eb3ca2506",
    urls = [
        "https://mirror.bazel.build/github.com/bazelbuild/bazel-skylib/releases/download/1.3.0/bazel-skylib-1.3.0.tar.gz",
        "https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel-skylib/releases/download/1.3.0/bazel-skylib-1.3.0.tar.gz",
    ],
)

load("@bazel_skylib//:workspace.bzl", "bazel_skylib_workspace")

bazel_skylib_workspace()

local_repository(
    name = "org_tensorflow",
    path = "tensorflow"
)

load("@org_tensorflow//tensorflow:workspace3.bzl", "tf_workspace3")
tf_workspace3()
load("@org_tensorflow//tensorflow:workspace2.bzl", "tf_workspace2")
tf_workspace2()
load("@org_tensorflow//tensorflow:workspace1.bzl", "tf_workspace1")
tf_workspace1()
load("@org_tensorflow//tensorflow:workspace0.bzl", "tf_workspace0")
tf_workspace0()
```

BUILD

```
load("@org_tensorflow//tensorflow:tensorflow.bzl", "tf_cc_binary")

tf_cc_binary(
    name = "test",
    srcs = ["test.cc"],
    deps = [
        "@org_tensorflow//tensorflow/compiler/mlir/lite:tf_to_tfl_flatbuffer",
    ],
)
```

test.cc

```
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    std::cout << "Hello World!" << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

And the local tensorflow repository is commit hash 0db597d0d758aba578783b5bf46c889700a45085 of the official tensorflow github. I'm using this version to be compatible with other repo in the full project.

The dependency to `"@org_tensorflow//tensorflow/compiler/mlir/lite:tf_to_tfl_flatbuffer"` triggers the duplication; there's no problem without it.

Also, this same code run without the problem on Mac OS with M1.

Any suggestions to handle this problem? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who have same problem,
adding `build --define tsl_protobuf_header_only=true` option into `.bazelrc` file resolved the issue. This flag add the protobuf library into the binaries explicitly.